# Dynamic colouration of zones visualized by a flying camera

Tags: opencv

i have an image (img_tot) printed on a plane and a down-facing camera flying on it and acquiring a frame, every time step "k", of a portion of such a plane.
i have to store all the images (one each time step) representing img_tot with the portion represented by frame(k) coloured in a certain way.
As if i had to highlight all the zones visualized by the camera in the plane
How can I do that through  Opencv??

Comment: Could you show us some examples? For me it's hard to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: mmm..i don't have a video o something like that. the concept can be explained as a  flashlight pointing on a dark plane. Only the area pointed becomes visible. i have to create an effect like that.

ps. the camera and the plane are simulated